# annotation based security in tomcat webapp

Tags: web-services, jersey, jaas

I want to achieve webservice security something like this 
(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm - example is for javaee)

But inside tomcat + jersey application. Is it possible to do so ?

As far as I can see, tomcat does have annotation-api which can work in this case. Unable to figure out how.

```
package samples.helloworld;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.annotation.Security.RolesAllowed;


@Path("/helloworld")
@RolesAllowed({"ADMIN", "ORG1"})
public class helloWorld {

   @GET
   @Path("sayHello")  
   @Produces("text/plain")
   @RolesAllows("ADMIN")
   public String sayHello() {
      return "Hello World!";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the link above, you should secure your Rest WebServices. Example  of Web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
         <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>Orders</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/orders</url-pattern>
             <http-method>GET</http-method>
             <http-method>POST</http-method>
         </web-resource-collection>
         <auth-constraint>
             <role-name>admin</role-name> 
         </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
        <login-config>
            <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
            <realm-name>default</realm-name>
        </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Hi @Michael My issue is not that simple. As per above its container managed. I need something that works out of the box...roles needs to be created dynamically...Anyways but for question asked...I assume your answer works.